# Find out the language of an ASPX file

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to find out if the ASPX file was written in C# or vb just by looking at the web page online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no there isn't.. unless the author were to comment it in somewhere.

Comment: I remember when coldfusion had an issue where a certain character in the URL would expose the source code... those were the old days.

Answer (score 2):

Get it to throw an unhandled exception:
[image]
<sub>(source: [dotnetslackers.com](http://dotnetslackers.com/images/articleimages/WebPartExportManager.PNG))</sub>

Depending on how exception handling is set up on the server, you may get the filename, whose extension will provide a clue.

This is very unlikely, but it's the only thing I can think of.